# unable to segment theora vorbis video file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

i am trying to split ogg video into 10 sec ogg video segments with ffmpeg segmenter.

```
ffmpeg -i www/VideoPlayer/Videos/wr3libvorbis.ogg -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list www/VideoPlayer/Videos/wr3libvorbis.m3u8 -acodec libvorbis www/VideoPlayer/Videos/wr3libvorbis%03d.ogg
```

I got following error:

```
[ogg @ 0x9bda5e0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1: 567505 >= 567505
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

with `-acodec flaac` i could successfully segment the video. what extra options should i need to give, to segment into vorbis audio codec video?

Comment: Have you tried playing the `.ogg` file with a player like VLC and see if that complains about the file. There might be a problem in the metadata in the file, which not necessarily prevents you from playing it but confuses ffmpeg.

Comment: @Anthon vlc player playing the video without any errors or warning. and also flaac audio codec segmented files are playing well.

Comment: Does it work if you add `-vcodec libtheora` ?

Comment: @Sukminder output segments with codec libtheora and libflaac are fine. but output segments with codec libtheora and libvorbis are giving error.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. Could it be this? http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/222 are your libraries up to date?

Comment: @Sukminder no its not that ticket and my libraries are up to date. I think there should be few extra options to segment a vorbis audio.